# Facebook API send messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook4j

I'm trying to figure out how to, or if it is allowed or possible to send messages using the Facebook API.

I am using the Facebook graph API from Facebook4j.

It seems that I can get a user's messages from getInbox(), but I can't see anyway to create a message?

I really only want to respond to Page messages using a Page access token, user messages are not required, but would be nice too.

Anyone know how, or if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I ended up with is,

to get all messages,

```
RawAPIResponse res = getConnection().callGetAPI("/" + connection.getPage().getId() + "/conversations");
JSONObject result = res.asJSONObject();
JSONArray conversations = result.getJSONArray("data");
```

and to send a message,

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("message", text);
connection.callPostAPI("/" + conversationId + "/messages", params);
```

It works, but a little ugly. Hopefully Facebook4J will support this API soon.

Answer (score 3):

Those links will tell you how to reply to messages with a Page Token:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/page/conversations
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/conversation/messages

In general, just do a POST request to this endpoint: `/{conversation-id}/messages`

Comment: Any idea when Facebook4j will support this?

Comment: well, it´s a simple API call. i am sure you can do simple API calls with Facebook4js, else it would not be useful anyway ;)

Comment: i´ve never used Facebook4j, but it took me 1 minute to find example code with a raw POST request: http://facebook4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Comment: Thanks this works, ugly because you need to walk the JSON objects yourself, but okay for now.  Hopefully Facebook4j will support this soon.